# How can I show a series of random images in a WordPress text widget using HTML/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, text, random, widget

I'm using WordPress 3.0.5 on Dreamhost, trying to create a text widget in the sidebar that will show a random set of nine (9) client logos. There are a total of 12 logos, located in the /wp-content/clients folder, named logo1.jpg thru logo12.jpg.

The idea is to choose the first image randomly, then get the next eight images in sequential order to avoid duplicates.

***UPDATE***

Got it working, thanks for the tips everyone!

Here is the final, working version:

```
<div id="client-logos"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

TotalLogos = 12;    
FirstPart = '<img src="/wp-content/clients/logo';
LastPart = '.jpg" height="50" width="110" />';

var r = Math.ceil(Math.random() * TotalLogos);

var content = document.getElementById('client-logos').innerHTML;
document.getElementById('client-logos').innerHTML = FirstPart + r + LastPart;

var t=0;
for (t=0;t<8;t++)
   {
      if (r == TotalLogos) { r=0; }
      r++;
      var content = document.getElementById('client-logos').innerHTML;
      document.getElementById('client-logos').innerHTML = content + FirstPart + r + LastPart;
   }

</script>
```

Comment: For a start, CLOSE YOUR IMAGE TAG!

Comment: And your for loop setup should have a <= like so: (t=0; t <= 8; t++) Although this will show 10 logos in total as you have already output one before the loop so really you want strictly less than: (t=0; t < 8; t++) If you think this will output 8 logos, try counting from 0 to 7 inclusive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

document.write() runs before the page finishes loading..
you should use something else..

first of all, you should get object of your div container by id:

your html:

```
    <div id="containerid"></div>

<script>
var elem = document.getElementById('containerid');
elem.innerHTML= "FirstPart + r + LastPart";
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Doc! The solution must involve innerHTML, based on what a quick Google search has told me, but I can't quite get it to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks again, DSL. It took me a while to get this working, because I was still putting the code within a function, which was screwing things up. I'll add my final working code above...

Answer (score 0):

Just change `t=8` to `t<8` and it works (for me). The second expression in a `for` loop means: "Execute the foor loop as long as this is true". Your code has to be executed as long as `t < 8`; when `t == 8`, it should stop.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/m7m7C/

Comment: Thanks pimvdb, nice catch! Now how to display the images without using document.write(), which as DrStrangeLove pointed out is main problem...

Comment: You can use jQuery to execute a function after all document functions are available. So, `document.wirte` does work then. If possible, try using jQuery - but then again, I don't know anything about WordPress and how to integrate jQuery into it.

Comment: I do loves me some jQuery, but was able to achieve the desired effect without it - and without too much code. See above, and thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm not sure if you are new to Stack Overflow, but the way to show thanks here is to please accept the answer that was the solution for you. ;)